# 2 UIButtons to hide / unHide same UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, boolean, operators

I'm new to swift and programming. I want to learn the best way to approach this.

I have a UIButton in my viewController ( storyboard ), and I have another UIButton in a UIView placed in that same VC.

The first button will hide/unhide the view.

The second UIButton, only shown when myView is unHidden, I want that button to hide myview as well. So two buttons to hide, one button to unhide.

I'm sure I can simplify this?

The second button is not working. What could I be missing?
import UIKit

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var outside: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var inside: UIView!
    
    var outsideBool: Bool = false
    var insideBool: Bool = false
    
    var myIndex: Int = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myView.isHidden = true
        print(insideBool)
        print(outsideBool)
    }

    @IBAction func outsideButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        outsideBool.toggle()
        print(outsideBool)
        if outsideBool && myIndex == 1 {
            myView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            if !outsideBool && myIndex == 1 || !outsideBool == !insideBool && myIndex == 1 {
                myView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func innerButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        insideBool.toggle()
    }
}
```

Updated Code Idea, but not working as hoped:

```
import UIKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
        
        @IBOutlet weak var outside: UIButton!
        
        @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var inside: UIView!
        
        var outsideBool: Bool = false
        var insideBool: Bool = false
        
        var myIndex: Int = 1
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            myView.isHidden = true
            print(insideBool)
            print(outsideBool)
        }
        
        func duh() {
            if outsideBool && myIndex == 1 {
                myView.isHidden = false
            } else if !outsideBool && myIndex == 1 {
                myView.isHidden = true
            } else if !insideBool && myIndex == 1 {
                myView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    
        @IBAction func outsideButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
            outsideBool.toggle()
            duh()
        }
        
        @IBAction func innerButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
            insideBool.toggle()
            duh()
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: your outsideButtonAction function seems a bit messed up.  Why don't you use outsideBool?  You never toggle it, and you never compare it.

Comment: I just realized that, and will edit / update my question. Thank you.

Comment: I got it!  I create a func that switch / cases the outsideBool, I compare that value first to hide or unhide the view, then after that comparison, in the false case, I compare the innerBool value and hide the view.  Still clumsy I feel, but its working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Bools in your case. Also buttons outlets are not needed so far.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet private weak var myView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myView.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func outerrButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    myView.isHidden.toggle()
}

@IBAction func innerButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    myView.isHidden = true
}
}
```

You can even simplify it and drag Touch Up Inside actions of both buttons to the same @IBAction:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet private weak var myView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myView.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func buttonsAction(_ sender: Any) {
    myView.isHidden.toggle()
}
}
```

View hierarchy is the following: [image: Main.storyboard]